# Is there a query that helps to track availability of the service in Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I'm trying to create a graph that will display the percentage of availability of the service, so I will know when the service was down and up. But I cannot find the right query to do this with Prometheus, is there a one or we should improvise somehow?

Answer (score 0):

First use the [Blackbox Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter) to probe your services over HTTP, HTTPS, DNS, TCP, ICMP and gRPC, then use the Blackbox "probe_success" metric and the Prometheus "avg_over_time" function to know the availability of the services.

For example, the following PromQL returns the availability of the services in the last week:

```
avg_over_time(probe_success[1w])*100
```